# Is there any difference between timed interval and time interval?

Tags: phrases

For instance, 'a ramp-like increase (or decrease) of neural activity that peaks at the end of a timed interval'. Can I repace 'timed interval' with 'time interval' without changing the original meaning?

Answer (score 2):

A **time interval** is just that, the amount of time between a **start** and **finish** time.

> From 12:00 to 12:15 is a 15 minute **time interval**

A **timed interval** is a **specific amount of time that has been purposely measured** as in an athletic competition

> Runners were started at **timed intervals**

A **timed interval** is an **interval of time**, but an **interval of time** is not necessarily a **timed interval**